# Assetic and twig inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

Hello i try to combine my js with yui filter from assetic

I have a first twig layout (template.html.twig) with some js assetics declarations :

```
{% block javascripts %}
{% javascripts 
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/jquery.remodal.min.js'
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/ajax/comiti.ajax.search.js'
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/init.js'
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/external/Chart.min.js'
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/charts.js'
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/comiti.villes-france.js'
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/external/jquery.validate.min.js'
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/comiti.form-validation.js'
    '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.js'
    '//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'
    '//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js'
    '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js'
    '//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js'
    '//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js'
    '//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js'
    '//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.print.min.js'
    filter='yui_js'
%}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

{% endblock %}

Then i try to override this block in my childs templates :

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
{% javascripts 
    'bundles/comitiapp/js/comiti.cart.js'
    filter='yui_js'
%}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

{% endblock %}

I exepected that assetic:dump would combine all the js in the same file but it produces multiples files : 1 for template.html.twig and 1 per child template.
Is that normal behaviour ? On the other hand, assetic:dump is really really slow in local . How to speed up in dev env ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the normal behviour. Each `{% javascripts %}` tag will output a Javascript file, `{{ parent() }}` outputs the JS file generated by the parent template, but does not merge with the child `javascripts` tag.

Comment: would it be a better comportement to merge qith the parent file

Comment: There is no such thing, and I don't think you would want it if there was. Files generated by `javascripts` are generated live at runtime, and then cached. If the list of compiled files changes from one page to another, this breaks any possibility of caching files, and thus reduces your performances. Why do you need so much to only have 1 file?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the behaviour you want. Two seperate files are better:

Because of browser caching, the large .js file is loaded once and applied to all pages while the site-specific parts are added when needed. Thats the most efficient way.